# PHP array input with single spaces not in new line

Tags: php, arrays, input

I am new in PHP. I want to take input of an array from user in a single line with single white spaces
like `5 6 2 1 4` but my code is taking inputs like

```
5  
6  
2  
1  
4
```

and then it is giving desired output.
 Here is my code-

```
 <?php 
    $fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");  
    fscanf($fp, "%d", $m);  
    $ar = array();` 
    for ($i=0; $i<$m; $i++) {
        fscanf($fp, "%d ", $ar[$i]);
    }  
    ?>
```

Please Help me.
[Here is the problem I want so solve](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/quicksort1)

Comment: If you want to participate in some kind of “hacker challenge”, you should go learn some basics first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use function implode http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
```

Answer (score 0):

Use readline() then explode() string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the user input into an array, try this

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$input = fgets($fp);
$ar = explode(' ',$input);

// remote the next line
var_dump($ar);

// don't forget to sanitize/filter integers
```